# How to implement a portable MySQL and connect to it from Ruby as a non-root under Linux

Tags: mysql, ruby

The key limitation for me is I am a non-root. I can do things only under my own space without any sudo permissions.

So I have to implement a portable MySQL and connect it from the mysql gem. But how to config for the mysql gem? While using gem to install it(I have already changed the GEM_HOME), it keeps showing:

```
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
```

But can anyone tell me how to use the configuration options? My local mysql is under `~/mysql`

Comment: Non-root shouldn't be a problem, given that even the standard port of MySQL is above 1024, right?

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED, or, better yet, a unix domain socket that can be controlled with the standard [Mandatory Access Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) and [Discretionary Access Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretionary_access_control).

Comment: I think the MySQL is not the problem, the problem is some dependent package - like `libmysqlclient-dev`, I am not sure how to install that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you switch to SQLite ? it allows connections to a file, no compilation needed.

Comment: Thanks, but I try to move to SQLite, but I met the same problem: while installing the gem for SQLite, there is an error:`qlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite3-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).`